# Functional testing and external api

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I'm writing a facebook app using framework that follows MVC pattern - Kohna 3.2. I want to test my server-side code. I decided to write unit tests for models, and functional tests to check controllers/views. Decided to use PHPUnit for both.

So I encountered a problem quickly. How can I write function test for controller that uses external api during request processing?

I don't want to use real api calls. Their execution takes much time and requires authentication token in session, that expires shortly. Also testing stuff like 'writing posts on wall' would generate a lot of spam.

I can't really see how to mock this. Ofcourse I can create a mock object for external api wrapper library, but I thought that functional test should be made by creating a request and checking its response. So I fail to see a place where I could inject the mock object..

How would you do it?

Comment: So you want to implement fake API to test your code? Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reviewing my own unanswered questions, I can reply to myself that using DIC (dependency injection container) is the answer. It lets having different configuration for test enviornment, or when using single PHP process during testing it's even possible to setup mocks just before performing a test.

Answer (score 2):

1) When testing **something, which works with the API wrapper**, you should mock the whole API wrapper class and simulate throwing exceptions as a error states and testing, how the application itself will react to these exceptions.

It should probably stop doing some operations, which were dependent on API response and it should probably show some user-friendly error.

Even more, you can (and probably should) test which methods on the API wrapper were called + how many times and which parameters were passed.

```
<?php

public function testShowUser() {
    $fb = $this->getMock( 'Facebook\Api' );
    $fb->expects( $this->once() ) // if your library will call getUserInfo() more than once or never, the test will fail
        ->method( 'getUserInfo' )
        ->with( $this->equalTo( 'johndoe' ) ) // if the method will be called with different parameter, the test will fail
        ->will( $this->throwException( 'Facebook\NonExistingUser' ) );

    $myApp = new MyApp( $fb );
    $myApp->renderUser( 'johndoe' ); // if this will throw uncaught exception, the test will fail

    $this->assertEquals(
        array( 'The user you requested does not exist' ),
        $myApp->getFlashMessages()
    );
}
```

2) When testing **the API wrapper itself** you can mock raw response from the API.

You should separate the whole stuff around HTTP communication to some specific class (Curl wrapper /with its own unit tests/) and assume that the server returned some specific HTTP code and response.

You could save all possible types of responses in files, so you can load them in your tests as a response.

I would suggest doing it this way:

```
<?php

/**
 * @expectedException Facebook\NonExistingUser
 */
public function testUnavailableApi() {
    $curl = $this->getMock( 'CurlWrapper' );
    $curl->expects( $this->once() )
        ->method( 'getBody' )
        ->will( $this->returnValue( file_get_contents( 'fb_404_response.json' ) ) );
    $curl->expects( $this->once() )
        ->method( 'getStatusCode' )
        ->will( $this->returnValue( 404 ) );

    $api = new Facebook\Api( $curl );
    $api->getUserInfo( 'johndoe' );
}
```

Comment: I know how to mock things. I just wonder, how could I inject those mocks when I create requests and test their results. From the time of posting this question the best answer I got so far is to use Dependency Injection Container, and configure it to use mock in a test, before forging the request.